# set foldername=!foldername:\=!Batch to rename all folders containing files having a specific pattern

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

Here's what I tried:

```
@echo off
REM Prefix zz_ to folders containing episodes with zz_
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
for /r "G:\itunes\Podcasts\" %%f in (zz_*.mp3) do (
   set N=%%~pf~
   set N=!N:\itunes\Podcasts\=!
   set N=!N:\=!
if exist %%f ren "g:%%~pf" "zz_!N!"
)
pause
```

But I received the error message: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
I'm not a programmer by any means, just a cut & paste kinda guy, so thanks for any assistance.

So what's wrong with the above is of course I am modifying the sub-directories while trying to recurse the directory (g:\itunes\podcasts). So the following clunky code does work, with one exception.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
REM Prefix zz_ to folders containing episodes with zz_
for /r "G:\itunes\Podcasts\" %%f in (zz_*.mp3) do (
   set foldername=%%~pf
   set foldername=!foldername:~17!
   set foldername=!foldername:\=!
   if exist %%f echo if exist %%f ren "g:%%~pf" "zz_!foldername!" >>g:\trash.bat
)
call g:\trash.bat
del g:\trash.bat

pause
```

It doesn't handle filenames containing exclamation marks. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are the .mp3 files in use? Because that's what that error message is suggesting.

Comment: Turn off `echo off` and see the bizarre stuff you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The following works, but is very clunky ... for one thing it continues to search a folder even after finding the 1st zz_podcast. And the idea of executing a batch file within a batch file may eventually cause me other problems with characters needing to be escaped. It's for the 2nd batch that I needed to make the percentage sign edits you see below. Would be nice if someone could think of a completely different approach, one more elegant perhaps?

```
@echo off
REM Prefix zz_ to folders containing episodes with zz_
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
REM The following recurses g:\itunes\podcasts looking for zz_ podcasts
for /r "G:\itunes\Podcasts\" %%f in (zz_*.mp3) DO (
set "filename=%%f"
set "filepath=%%~pf"
set "foldername=%%~pf"
REM Delayed Expansion needed here for edits to file, path & folder names
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set filename2=!filename:%%=%%%%!
set filepath=!filepath:%%=%%%%!
set foldername=!foldername:~17!
set foldername=!foldername:\=!
set foldername=!foldername:%%=%%%%!
if exist "!filename!" echo if exist "!filename2!" ren "g:!filepath!" "zz_!foldername!" >>g:\trash.bat
endlocal
)
REM trash.bat has its own issues with escaped characters
call g:\trash.bat
del g:\trash.bat
```

What this was all about. When I edit podcast tags I often need to see the unedited podcast "in context" in order to decide the best way forward. For example if a podcast has 'rebroadcast' in its title, then I need to make sure I have the original before deleting it. So I temporarily tag podcasts as zz_, and then open up the entire zz_ folder to see the zz_episode "in context"